# How to enable feedback in Azure Virtual Assistant — TypeScript Template

Tags: typescript, azure, botframework

I tried to implement Feedbacks in TypeScript template of Virtual Assistant but could not find any proper document or example.

This is not the only case, there are many cases where only C# examples are given. Please provide TypeScript examples or any proper documentation.

Comment: whats the question here?

Comment: I was using Typescript template of Azure's Virtual Assistant. I wanted to do some modification in its feedback. But I could not find any resources for TypeScript, neither in official documentation nor anywhere else.

Comment: the issue is being tracked in https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/3812